# Google Apps Scripts - Sheets - Moving variable number of rows from one tab to another

Tags: google-apps-script, google-sheets

To begin I know very little about writing code. I would like to move rows from one tab to another in a google sheets.

At the moment I am using the below script to move a single row when an action is done. When column 17 is marked "Completed" in the 'Work' tab, it copies the entire row, creates a row in the 'completed' tab, pastes the copied row into that new row, and then deletes the copied row. The information inputted into 'Work' is a query array from another tab, 'data', that itself uses the info from 'completed' with an arrayformula + vlookup to filter what shows up in 'Work'. So when an entry is completed and moves to that tab, it will not reappear in 'Work'.

```
function onEdit(event) {
  var ss = SpreadsheetApp.getActiveSpreadsheet();
  var s = event.source.getActiveSheet();
  var r = event.source.getActiveRange();
if(s.getName() == "Work" && r.getColumn() == 17 && r.getValue() == "Completed") {
    var row = r.getRow();
    var numColumns = s.getLastColumn();
    var targetSheet = ss.getSheetByName("completed");
    var target = targetSheet.getRange(2, 1);
    targetSheet.insertRows(2)
    s.getRange(row, 1, 1, numColumns).moveTo(target);
    s.deleteRow(row);
    ss.toast('Complete');
  }
```

However I want to change this so that instead of being an onEdit function, it will be its own function that will detect any rows with column 17 marked "Completed" in 'Work', copy them, create the number of rows in 'completed' that were copied, pastes those rows in, and deletes them in 'Work'. Then I will attach this to an image I will be able to click to run it.

I have tried fiddling with the above code to achieve this, with no luck. Any direction on how to move a variable number of rows to a new tab would be greatly appreciated!

Answer (score 0):

I believe your goal is as follows.

- You want to check all values of the column "Q" on `Work` sheet and when the value of column "Q" is `Completed`, you want to move the row to `completed` sheet.
- You want to achieve this without using `onEdit`.

In this case, how about the following modified script?

#### Modified script:

```js
function myFunction() {
  var ss = SpreadsheetApp.getActiveSpreadsheet();
  var sheet = ss.getSheetByName("Work");
  
  // 1. Values are retrieved from `Work` sheet.
  var data = sheet.getDataRange().getValues();
  
  // 2. Retrieve the rows including `Completed` at the column "Q" and the rows not including it.
  var copiedData = data.reduce((o, r) => {
    o[r[16] == "Completed" ? "copy" : "leave"].push(r);
    return o;    
  }, {copy: [], leave: []});
  
  // 3. Retrieve values from `completed` sheet and add the rows including `Completed` at the column "Q".
  var targetSheet = ss.getSheetByName("completed");
  var targetRange = targetSheet.getRange(2, 1, targetSheet.getLastRow() - 1, targetSheet.getLastColumn());
  var targetValues = targetRange.getValues();
  var newValues = copiedData.copy.concat(targetValues);

  // 4. Clear `completed` sheet and put the new values.
  targetRange.clearContent();
  targetSheet.getRange(2, 1, newValues.length, newValues[0].length).setValues(newValues);
  
  // 5. Clear `Work` sheet and put the rows not including `Completed` at the column "Q".
  sheet.clearContents();
  sheet.getRange(1, 1, copiedData.leave.length, copiedData.leave[0].length).setValues(copiedData.leave);

  ss.toast('Complete');
}
```

- The flow of this modification is as follows.

  1. Values are retrieved from `Work` sheet.
  2. Retrieve the rows including `Completed` at the column "Q" and the rows not including it.
  3. Retrieve values from `completed` sheet and add the rows including `Completed` at the column "Q".
  4. Clear `completed` sheet and put the new values.
  5. Clear `Work` sheet and put the rows not including `Completed` at the column "Q".
- When you assign the above function to an image on Spreadsheet, you can run the script by clicking the image button.

#### References:

- [reduce()](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/Array/reduce)
- [clearContent() of Class Range](https://developers.google.com/apps-script/reference/spreadsheet/range#clearContent())
- [clearContents() of Class Sheet](https://developers.google.com/apps-script/reference/spreadsheet/sheet#clearcontents)
- [setValues(values)](https://developers.google.com/apps-script/reference/spreadsheet/range#setvaluesvalues)